# Custom adapter setOnItemClickListener parent.getItemAtPosition() always null

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a custom adapter giving custom views to a listview (a few fields and an image). I've changed something, and for some reason my clickListener method parent.getItemAtPosition(position) is always returning null. Not sure how the change I made has made this effect. When stepping through it, it fires correctly, but for some reason the value is always null. Is there anything you can see?

```
ListView airportResults = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listAirportResults );
List<SearchResultsItem> items = getSearchResults(searchTerm);
ResultsAdapter = new SearchResultsAdapter(this, items);
airportResults.setAdapter(ResultsAdapter);
```

My getSearchResults(searchTerm) returns the items in the listview with the following type:

```
List<SearchResultsItem>
```

Then the onclick listener:

```
airportResults.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long duration) {
            String sClickedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

           //do something with sClickedItem
        }
    });
```

From the above code, the **position** parameter is correct (I tap on the first item, position=0; I tap on the 4th item, position=3 etc). The parent and view objects all have values. However, the **sClickedItem** is always null.

Many thanks,
J

Comment: It could possibly be related to how you've implemented the adapter. Have you tried parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)

Comment: Still null. In the variables debugger, I can expand the adapter and view the items in the list (parent > mAdapter > items > ...).

Comment: Did you extend BaseAdapter? If so you might have to override to make your own getItem(position) method. ArrayAdapter will handle this for you, but I don't think BaseAdapter will.

Comment: Found it - it was my custom implementation. Thanks for your help. Answer below

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It was my implementation of my custom adapter.

```
    airportResults.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long duration) {
            TextView textViewIata = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_searchresults_iata);
            String clickedIataValue = (String) textViewIata.getText();
```

As I wasn't using standard objects, I had to make my own implementation. Simply: my view was a cutsom XML layout with various textviews in it, so I just had to **view.findViewById()** (because the **view** is the currently selected item in the listview) and **getText()** that way instead.

Thanks for making me realise this

J